# Finding the missing values based on criteria in Column C

Tags: vba, excel

I have a value in column C which in some cases are duplicated, where there are duplicates I want it to look in column Z for the corresponding ID if none exist I want it to check where whether any other values in column C have a value in Column Z and then add the missing values into column Z accordingly:

```
Column C         Column Z   
45519            Blank*
45519            1 
456              2
456              *Blank
```

Expected result:

```
Column C:        Column Z
45519                1
45519                1
456                  2
456                  2
```

Stackoverflow Code I have adapted to use 1 and 24 respectively.

```
 Sub test()

 Dim wb As Workbook
 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("transactions")
 lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
 Dim dataArr()
 dataArr = ws.Range("C1:Z" & lastRow).Value
 Dim currentRow As Long
 Dim dict As Object

 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 For currentRow = LBound(dataArr, 1) To UBound(dataArr, 2)
 If Not IsEmpty(dataArr(currentRow, 2)) And Not dict.Exists(dataArr
 (currentRow, 1)) Then
    dict.Add dataArr(currentRow, 1), dataArr(currentRow, 2)
End If
Next currentRow
For currentRow = LBound(dataArr, 1) To UBound(dataArr, 1)

If IsEmpty(dataArr(currentRow, 2)) Then

    dataArr(currentRow, 2) = dict(dataArr(currentRow, 1))
 End If

Next currentRow

ws.Range("C1").Resize(UBound(dataArr, 1), UBound(dataArr, 2)) = dataArr

End Sub
```

I am receiving no result in column Z as a result of this

[image: Before Macro]
[image: After Macro]

Comment: Your array doesn't have 24 dimensions, it has 2.

Comment: I have changed the code and ran and receiving no result

Comment: Have you stepped through the code and checked what is going on? I think you are confusing the number of dimensions of an array and its size. Your array has 2 dimensions but you are only considering the 1st `dataArr(currentRow, 1)` and 2nd columns `dataArr(currentRow, 2)`. If you want to look at Z you need to refer to the 24th column (not 24th dimension).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some tidying up to do. Currently assumes data starts in row 2.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("transactions")
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim unionRng As Range
    Set unionRng = Union(ws.Range("C2:C" & lastRow), ws.Range("Z2:Z" & lastRow))

    Dim dataArray()
    Dim numberOfColumns As Long
    numberOfColumns = unionRng.Areas.Count

    ReDim dataArray(1 To lastRow, 1 To numberOfColumns) '1 could come out into variable startRow
    Dim currRow As Range

    Dim columnToFill As Long

    For columnToFill = 1 To numberOfColumns

        For Each currRow In unionRng.Areas(columnToFill)

            dataArray(currRow.Row - 1, columnToFill) = currRow 'assume data starts in row 1 otherwise if 2 then currRow.Row -1 etc

        Next currRow

    Next columnToFill


    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For currentRow = LBound(dataArray, 1) To UBound(dataArray, 1)

        If Not IsEmpty(dataArray(currentRow, 2)) And Not dict.Exists(dataArray(currentRow, 1)) Then
            dict.Add dataArray(currentRow, 1), dataArray(currentRow, 2)
        End If

    Next currentRow

    For currentRow = LBound(dataArray, 1) To UBound(dataArray, 1)

        If IsEmpty(dataArray(currentRow, 2)) Then

            dataArray(currentRow, 2) = dict(dataArray(currentRow, 1))
        End If

    Next currentRow

    ws.Range("Z2").Resize(UBound(dataArray, 1), 1) = Application.Index(dataArray, 0, 2)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Amended column references as per comments, plus I think your first loop was unnecessarily long. You'll need to change the 24s if your array is actually of a different size.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("transactions")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Dim dataArr()
dataArr = ws.Range("C1:Z" & lastRow).Value
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim dict As Object

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For currentRow = LBound(dataArr, 1) To UBound(dataArr, 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(dataArr(currentRow, 24)) And Not dict.Exists(dataArr(currentRow, 1)) Then
        dict.Add dataArr(currentRow, 1), dataArr(currentRow, 24)
    End If
Next currentRow

For currentRow = LBound(dataArr, 1) To UBound(dataArr, 1)
    If IsEmpty(dataArr(currentRow, 24)) Then
        dataArr(currentRow, 24) = dict(dataArr(currentRow, 1))
    End If
Next currentRow

ws.Range("C1").Resize(UBound(dataArr, 1), UBound(dataArr, 2)) = dataArr

End Sub
```

**Alternative method**

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("transactions")
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

Dim r As Range, r1 As Range, s As String

For Each r In ws.Range("Z1:Z" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    Set r1 = ws.Range("C1:C" & lastRow).Find(ws.Cells(r.Row, "C"), , , xlWhole)
    If Not r1 Is Nothing Then
        s = r1.Address
        Do Until r1.Row <> r.Row
            Set r1 = ws.Range("C1:C" & lastRow).FindNext(r1)
            If r1.Address = s Then Exit Do
        Loop
        r.Value = ws.Cells(r1.Row, "Z")
    End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this. The ID is in column C and the value I want to find is in Column Z. There is data in between, this unfortunately did not return a result.

Comment: Worked for me. Filled in the blank in Z1.

Comment: I have just amended the test data slightly as its not working for me :(

Comment: Are you definitely using the right worksheet? I just put 4 values in C1:C4 and three values in Z2:Z4. Is that what you envisaged?

Comment: In some cases in column Z there will be no ID for a value in Column C

Comment: Yes, hence Z1 is blank. Please post a screenshot of your sample data.

Comment: Hi, I have added a screen shot, it seems to be putting the ID in column C instead of in column Z.

Comment: I may have messed up! Back later.

Comment: I can return the Customer Numbers to as they were that's no problem

Comment: On reflection, I don't think there is a problem with the code, although I think there are better ways to solve this problem. Are you sure those values in C are the same - no trailing or leading spaces?

Comment: Yes no trailing spaces. Can I not just swap the result from C to Z? as it looks as though its just putting result in C. IE where there is an ID of 11764... This use to be 45978.

Comment: Can you post a small screenshot (only needs a few rows) of your data before the macro and after the macro? Meanwhile I will post an alternative approach,

Comment: I have added the before photo which is the first one now.

Comment: The problem is that none of your customer values 45519 has an ID. I have posted another solution but it will hit the same problem.

Comment: Yes, this can be the case where the customer values may not have an ID at all.

Comment: As it stands that code cannot be putting col Z entries in col C so something else must be going on. Did you try the other code?

Comment: The alternative code seemed to work and then went to an unresponsive state

Comment: Think I've sorted that now.

Answer (score 0):

you could very simply go like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range, IdsRng As Range

    With Worksheets("transactions") 'reference wanted sheet
        Set IdsRng = .Range("Z2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) 'get all IDs from its column Z cells with constant numeric value

        With .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)) 'reference referenced sheet column C cells from row 1 (header) down to last not empty one
            For Each cell In IdsRng 'loop through all IDs
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.Offset(, -23).value ' filter referenced cells on 1st column with passed ID content 'filter referenced range with current ID
                .Offset(1, 23).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).value = IdsRng.value 'write all filtered cells corresponding values in column Z with current ID
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```